# PHP echoing with dodgy syntax?

Tags: php, html, syntax, echo, brackets

I was having some slight issues while working on a project. I had the following php inside my work:

```
echo('<div class="mailboxhold" style="display:flex; height: auto; font-size: 2vw; justify-content:space-around; align-content: space-between; flex-direction: column;"'>);
echo("<img class='postimg' src='".$postpath."' alt='post'>"); # NEXT STEP NEED TO INTEGRATE POST DETAILS AND MAKE MULTIPLE POST DISPLAY
echo($postcaption);
```

Which gave me the following error message:

```
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\UwAmp\www\grav1ty\bio.php on line 106
```

I've looked at Stack overflow's page on this type of error and am still unsure of how to proceed... :(

Any suggestions? (ignore the variables by the way, they're fine...)

Comment: you have the `>` outside the closing quote on the first line

Answer (score 3):

Like Phiter has said, you have the > outside the closing quote. This is the correct syntax:

```
echo('<div class="mailboxhold" style="display:flex; height: auto; font-size: 2vw; justify-content:space-around; align-content: space-between; flex-direction: column;">');
```

If you have access to a command line with PHP, you can test the syntax with this command:

```
php -l filename.php
```